# Sorting items in a text file in python

Tags: python, sorting

I've been trying to figure out how to sort results in a text file in order of test scores for a small task I'm doing using the lambda sort function. I'm unsure if this is the best way to do this or not but it was recommended to me by a friend.

The results are entered into the text file like so:

```
    text_file = open("Results.txt", "a")
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write(str(score))
    text_file.write(" ")
    text_file.write(userName)
    text_file.write(" ")
    text_file.write(userClass)
    text_file.close()
```

My current sorting system looks like this:

```
with open("Results.txt") as inf:
data = []
for line in inf:
    line = line.split()
    if len(line)==4:
        data.append(line)

a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x.modified, reverse=True)
```

And the text file looks like this:

```
5 Test b
4 Test b
6 Test c
7 Test a
```

(score userName userClass)

I would like to sort the results in descending order by score and I'm not sure this is the correct way to go about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `x.modified`?

Comment: Have you tried running the code?  What results do you get?

Comment: Why `if len(line)==4:` when you only have 3 elements in each line (score, userName and userClass)?

Comment: what is `a` supposed to be in your code? And dtw, you have to add a level of indentation after `with open...`

Comment: as @BhargavRao asks, `x.modified` has no meaning. Your `data` list consists of lists with 3 elements. So you should use `key=lambda x: x[0]` instead.

Comment: The code you've posted make little sense and isn't properly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need list element as sublists, the above answers are ok. 
but if your need is just to sort the results

```
with open("Results.txt") as inf:
data = []
for line in inf:
    line = line.split()
    if len(line)==3:
        data.append(tuple(line)) #append as tuple

>>> data #as result of codes
[('5', 'Test', 'b'), ('4', 'Test', 'b'), ('6', 'Test', 'c'), ('7', 'Test', 'a')]
>>> data.sort()
>>> data #ascending order
[('4', 'Test', 'b'), ('5', 'Test', 'b'), ('6', 'Test', 'c'), ('7', 'Test', 'a')]
>>> data.sort(reverse=True)
>>> data # descending order
[('7', 'Test', 'a'), ('6', 'Test', 'c'), ('5', 'Test', 'b'), ('4', 'Test', 'b')]
```

then do whatever you want

**edit**

```
>>> for t in data:
...     print  " ".join(t)
... 
7 Test a
6 Test c
5 Test b
4 Test b
```

**edit 2.1** avoiding duplicates with `set()`

```
>>> with open('ex4.txt') as inf:
...     data = set()
...     for line in inf:
...             line = line.split()
...             if len(line)==3:
...                     data.add(tuple(line))
... 
>>> data
set([('2', 'Test', 'c'), ('0', 'Test', 'a'), ('1', 'Test', 'a'), ('3', 'Test', 'b')])
>>> list(data)
[('2', 'Test', 'c'), ('0', 'Test', 'a'), ('1', 'Test', 'a'), ('3', 'Test', 'b')]
>>>
```

**edit 2.2** avoiding duplicate records with if

```
>>> with open("ex4.txt") as inf:
...     data = []
...     for line in inf:
...             line = line.split()
...             if (len(line)==3) and (tuple(line) not in data): 
...                     data.append(tuple(line))
... 
>>> data
[('1', 'Test', 'a'), ('2', 'Test', 'c'), ('3', 'Test', 'b'), ('0', 'Test', 'a')]
```

Comment: Solution works perfectly :D but is there a way I can split them off and display each score on a separate line?

Comment: This is creating a double of a score every time its position in the list is changed...any way to delete previous results once they have been moved in the list?

Comment: excuse me, i didn't understand what you mean. can you just give an example?

Comment: 1 Test a
2 Test c
3 Test b
0 Test a
3 Test b

In this the result with score 3 has been in the file for the longest and has created duplicates because of this I can only assume. It seems that sorting it recreates results that were already in there and displays them in the correct order.

Comment: adding  `and tuple(line) not ind data` to if statement  will solve it. or assigning data as a `set()` and `add`ing tuples to this set, then convert in back to `list` is also possible solution. i'm updating the code.

Answer (score 1):

You want to sort on the first index of each `x` passed to your lamda, which will be an array in this case.  This code works for me (plus a few other changes to variables to make it work, as your example had invalid formatting, passed `a` instead of `data` to the `sorted()` function, and was only working on lines of 4 elements, not 3):

```
with open("Results.txt") as inf:
    data = []
    for line in inf:
        line = line.split()
        if len(line) == 3:
            data.append(line)

    a = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got no errors just doesn't sort results.

Comment: Here is a [working example](http://repl.it/lsw/2) that you can take a look at.  I'm guessing that due to the other errors in your sample, there's something else that's preventing you from being to integrate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort()` method  which modifies the list in-place. Your input file looks pretty straight forward that you can use a list comprehension to read it in. Since you know that the grades are in index 0, the `key` should be based on that index.

```
 with open("Results.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = [line.split() for line in f]
    data.sort(key = lambda x : x[0], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to process the sorted data or just have it printed?

```
>>> f = open('Results.txt')
>>> print '\n'.join(' '.join(l)for l in sorted((l.split()for l in f),
                                            key=lambda x: -int(x[0])))
7 Test a
6 Test c
5 Test b
4 Test b
>>>
```

More seriously, if your scores are integers usually you don't want to sort them in lexicographical order, otherwise "7" comes before "11" in reversed order...

Your `lambda` must (*must*) convert the string that comes from `split` to an integer and then pass the result to sorted; a more straightforward way to put  it is

```
>>> f = open('Results.txt')
>>> data = [l.split() for l in f]
>>> data.sort(key=lambda x: -int(x[0]))
```

---

#### Example

This is a direct cut&paste from the terminal:

```
$ cat Results.txt 
5 Test b
4 Test b
6 Test c
7 Test a
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open('Results.txt')
>>> print '\n'.join(' '.join(l)for l in sorted((l.split()for l in f),
...                                             key=lambda x: -int(x[0])))
7 Test a
6 Test c
5 Test b
4 Test b
>>> f = open('Results.txt')
>>> data = [l.split() for l in f]
>>> data.sort(key=lambda x: -int(x[0]))
>>> data
[['7', 'Test', 'a'], ['6', 'Test', 'c'], ['5', 'Test', 'b'], ['4', 'Test', 'b']]
>>>
```

The OP, in a comment, remarked a problem with an `IndexError` that I cannot replicate in my example... I can only ***guess*** that they are blindly applying my suggestion, that is linked to a specific data format, to a different use case...

Comment: Getting this error:

    line 118, in <lambda>
    key=lambda x: -int(x[0]))))
    IndexError: list index out of range

Unsure what it means...fairly new to python.

Comment: Your error usually happens when `x` (the individual item that is to be sorted) is not an indexable object, on the other hand the elements that are being sorted _should_ be lists... Is it possible that a mistake happened when you copy&pasted my code?